# Algorithms with different upper and lower bounds

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am preparing a list of algorithms for which big theta expression for (worst case) runtime is not known. This is for a class to demonstrate the point that tight analysis of an algorithm may not be easy at times. I am interested practically useful and hopefully simple (not required though) algorithms - importantly the Algorithms that are known that take finite time to finish - better yet the ones with polynomial runtime but that do not have matching upper and lower bounds of worst case runtime. A couple of points:

1. I am aware of problems with unknown time complexity - what I am interested in are the algorithms with unknown tight bound on runtime.
2. I believe that the lower bounds are usually harder to come by, so more interesting would be the algorithms whose suspected upper bounds are not yet proven.

Thanks.

Comment: An optimal algorithm to compute a minimum spanning tree is known, however even though we known that the algorithm must be optimal, its exact time complexity is unknown and lies in $\Omega(m) \cap O(m \cdot \alpha(m,n))$, where $n$ and $m$ are the number of vertices of the graph and $\alpha$ is the inverse Ackermann function. See https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/505241.505243 .